# How to use Custom map in MOBAC?

Tags: mobile-atlas-creator

I need to convert my own vector map(stored in Geoserver) to "mbtiles" using MOBAC(Mobile Atlas Creator). For Custom map, we need to write an xml file. I searched every where on internet But no where it is mentioned about where to keep the xml file(which folder) and what should be the name of the file. I am asking this question to you because I didn't get my answer anywhere.Please reply step by step.Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

1) get MOBAC from http://mobac.sourceforge.net/

2) unpack installer zip file

3)  create XML with custom source to **mapsources** folder. It has couple of jar files. My sample with Geoserver, replace here **url** and **layers** as minimum. Note that & must be escaped as end of sample URL.

> My sample:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
  <customWmsMapSource>
  <name>My Geoserver WMS</name>
  <minZoom>0</minZoom>
  <maxZoom>18</maxZoom>
  <tileType>PNG</tileType>
  <version>1.1.1</version>
  <layers>topp:states</layers>
  <url>http://kaart.maakaart.ee/geoserver/topp/wms?service=WMS&amp;</url>
  <coordinatesystem>EPSG:4326</coordinatesystem>
  <aditionalparameters></aditionalparameters>
  <backgroundColor>#000000</backgroundColor>
</customWmsMapSource>
```

4) Start Mobile_Atlas_Creator.jar / Mobile_Atlas_Creator.exe (depending on your OS)

5) As first dialog, it asks **Atlas name** (this will be your file name - choose anything you want) and Tile package format. Select **MBTiles SQLite** as format. Next MOBAC start may have the last atlas already open, use Atlas > New Atlas to create new.

6) Zoom map to your required area, and drag your map area on map - will be shown as red area. Map moving is a bit annoying -  in Mac right click moves map, scroll zooms, and left click selects area but it may be different on different OS.

7) Select zoom levels. Start with low zooms, e.g. 0, and select next ones until you have desired amount of details. For mobile use I suggest not to have more than about 10.000 tiles (one tile can be about 20KB, depending on source), so total package might be 200MB. Each next zoom will make package about 5x larger, so do not start with high zooms like 18. If you want high zooms, select smaller area (e.g. city center only). Zoom levels pane shows number of tiles.

8) Click **Add selection**. You should have something like follows
[image: Mobac with selections]

9) Click **Create Atlas** in left panel bottom, and your Atlas (MBTiles file) will be created after some download time to Atlases folder of MOBAC.

ps. You may want to select multiple layers, detailed zooms for smaller area

Comment: How to save as XYZ Cesium / OpenLayers compatible?

Answer (score 0):

On my system (linux, package: mobile-atlas-creator v1.9.16)  the mapsource directory is in

```
$HOME/.config/mobac/mapsources
```