# Save a WMS layer on your Hard Drive via QGIS?

Tags: qgis, wms, export, save

Well, here's another question. I'm working on a set of WMS data right now and i wanted to know if you can save it on a Hard drive. I do know that you can save the current view as a georeferenced Tif, but considering the resolution i need and space covered by my workspace i need something a lot faster or i'll be doing this for weeks.

Comment: You need to explain what you mean by 'save on Hard Drive'. Do you want to cache the images, so that you don't need to hit the service everytime? Or do you also want to in some way get the features so that you can fire off getFeature info requests?

Comment: I would like to get the features in some way indeed, i have the wms server with me, i can load the data with Qgis, but i can't tinker with it. Since i need to do a little processing on it before comparing said data with what i created a while ago, having it on my computer as a set of raster datas seems to be the best way to fit my needs.

Comment: If you need Features, then you need a WFS service, since WFS is meant for features, while WMS is just the rendered image from those features

Comment: I'll end needing both in the end but for now the rendered tif files might be what i should get first, now that i think about it. Also heard about something called Maperitive that might help me too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use GrassGis which is installed alongside with Qgis. There is the tool r.in.wms which will do the work.

It is in the background creating a textfile with the GetMap queries and replaces the extent for each tile. So you set it up with the correct region, the size of the tiles you want to have, the imagetype (depending what the wms offers) and thats it. It then sends the Queries automaticly one after the other using wget. After its finished you have to merge the tiles.

The downside is you need roughly 1-2 hours to be able to get along with GrassGis far enough to set the region extent and start the tool (GrassGis is pretty different from other Gi-Systems)

Comment: Ok, i did not know that. That'll be pretty damn usefull because the tool is really powerfull and a little bit easier to set up than WMS downloader (But that's mostly due to the fact that i was already working with some of it's modules so a LOT of the settings were set by my previous tinkering with Grass). The hardest part was actually to find a way to force him to dowload the Tif i wanted, since i didn't quite know if he asked for the name of the thing, it's id or it's path. But after much work, and i still don't quite know how, it worked and got the tiles smoothly. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 25):

In QGIS you can use R-Click and `Save As...` to save the WMS, and any other service, as a raster image.

[image]

It saves is at a tiff, and the resolution needs to be set by you. There are other expression and creation options as well.

Comment: this does it, just choose the projection and (if it's like google, bing or esri satellite) set resolution to 1 m

Comment: What if I just want everything same as the source? How can I set it up?

Comment: @user2720402 try the layer properties in most cases you will find the resolution there

Comment: works for me, just had to deselect "create VRT" to get around error Error " destination provider" when trying to save WMS as GeoTIFF

Comment: Is there any way to run this from the command line so that it can be run as a cron job?

Comment: What can be done if the resolution ist bad? I changed it to hor: 0.001 and verti: 0.001 but its still pixely. If get any further high with the resolution, the size of the file will be too big. (Over 300gb)

Comment: How can I do this in a pythonic way?

Answer (score 1):

If your WMS server allows users to cache data, and all that you require is the Imagery as a Base layer, you should look into using [Mobile Atlas Creator](http://mobac.sourceforge.net/)

I've successfully used MAC to create a mbtiles file, which can be viewed in QGIS, and is as good as an offline basemap, which you can place underneath your data.

For more information on how to use Mobile Atlas Creator, please have a look at this answer: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/72973/442

Comment: That'll be usefull, both for the datas i need and the osm tiles preset into the mapsource folder. I'll get back to you if i need a little more help and i'll try to use the link you provided to set the wms for now.

Comment: Well, the WMS i am trying to use seems to have a lot of incompabilities with MOBAC. Tried with both Geopal and Geoportail, then saw in the doc that the zoom levels from MOBAC makes it unable to open the tiles properly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i am trying an Arcgis plugin avaible as a standalone .exe. It's called WMS dowloader, avaible [here](http://geotrix.eu/) and i'll confirm later if it works but from what i've seen it might do the trick (It has a clear and simple UI at least)

After much work and a long download it seems WMS downloader worked alright for the task at hand. But i have to say, seting up that program was very tedious.