# GRASS r.in.wms: HTTP Error 505

Tags: qgis, wms, error, download, grass-7.0

I would like to download a terrestrial image from a WMS server. The Save as option in QGIS didn't work, so I tried to download it with the r.in.wms command from the GRASS shell as described at [SE: Save a WMS layer on your Hard Drive via QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190927/save-a-wms-layer-on-your-hard-drive-via-qgis). However, the r.in.wms module is broken (the method option is used twice in the run command and throws the error `Option <method> does not accept multiple answers`) and when I use the GRASS Shell of the above mentioned plugin I do get an HTTP error:

`r.in.wms url=http://85.18.173.22:8080/DbMAP_WMS/ORTOFOTO_2011/WMSservlet output=Orthofoto_2011 layers='Egeos 2011' wms_version=1.1.1 srs=3003 format=png`

`GRASS_INFO_ERROR(44976,1): HTTP Error 505: HTTP Version Not Supported`

Does anybody know what that error means or how I can fix it?

- QGIS version: 2.18.3
- GRASS 7 plugin
- WMS url: http://85.18.173.22:8080/DbMAP_WMS/ORTOFOTO_2011/WMSservlet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tried and the problem is the layer name. Grass gis has problems with the space in the layer name. It does work when you input the layer name as "Egeos%202011". Substituting the space (%20) or other special characters with the % notation often helps in html context.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be saying it doesn't support your version.

First [fetch the getcapabilites document](http://85.18.173.22:8080/DbMAP_WMS/ORTOFOTO_2011/WMSservlet?request=GetCapabilities) - which seems to indicate it should support version=1.1.1

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE WMT_MS_Capabilities SYSTEM "http://85.18.173.22:8080/DbMAP_WMS/capabilities_1_1_1.dtd" [<!ELEMENT VendorSpecificCapabilities EMPTY>]>
<WMT_MS_Capabilities version="1.1.1" updateSequence="1491294758094">
    <Service>
        <Name>OGC:WMS</Name>
        <Title>DbMAP WMS</Title>
        <Abstract>DbMAP WMS by ABACO S.p.A. (www.abacogroup.com)</Abstract>
        <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://www.abacogroup.com/"/>
    </Service>
    <Capability>
        <Request>
            <GetCapabilities>
                <Format>application/vnd.ogc.wms_xml</Format>
                <DCPType>
                    <HTTP>
                        <Get>
                            <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://85.18.173.22:8080/DbMAP_WMS/ORTOFOTO_2011/WMSservlet?" />
                        </Get>
                        <Post>
                            <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://85.18.173.22:8080/DbMAP_WMS/ORTOFOTO_2011/WMSservlet?" />
                        </Post>
                    </HTTP>
                </DCPType>
            </GetCapabilities>
            <GetMap>
                <Format>image/gif</Format>
                <Format>image/png</Format>
                <Format>image/jpeg</Format>
                <Format>image/bmp</Format>
                <Format>image/svg+xml</Format>
                <DCPType>
                    <HTTP>
                        <Get>
                            <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://85.18.173.22:8080/DbMAP_WMS/ORTOFOTO_2011/WMSservlet?" />
                        </Get>
                    </HTTP>
                </DCPType>
            </GetMap>
            <GetFeatureInfo>
                <Format>text/html</Format>
                <DCPType>
                    <HTTP>
                        <Get>
                            <OnlineResource xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:type="simple" xlink:href="http://85.18.173.22:8080/DbMAP_WMS/ORTOFOTO_2011/WMSservlet?" />
                        </Get>
                    </HTTP>
                </DCPType>
                <Format>text/xml</Format>
            </GetFeatureInfo>
        </Request>
        <Exception>
            <Format>application/vnd.ogc.se_xml</Format>
        </Exception>
        <Layer>
        <Name>_Main_Layer_</Name>
        <Title>Main Layer</Title>
        <SRS>EPSG:3004</SRS>
        <LatLonBoundingBox minx="-180" miny="-90" maxx="180" maxy="90"/>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:3004" minx="2249990.0" miny="4594199.0" maxx="2378813.75" maxy="4681672.0"/>
            <Layer>
                <Name>Egeos 2011</Name>
                <Title>Egeos 2011</Title>
        <BoundingBox SRS="EPSG:3004" minx="2249990.0" miny="4594199.0" maxx="2378813.75" maxy="4681672.0"/>
            </Layer>

        </Layer>
    </Capability>
</WMT_MS_Capabilities>
```

So next you need to check your layer name (Egeos 2011), format (image/png) and SRS (`3003`) and only `epsg:3004` is supported which is probably the problem.

Though the fact the server lies about it's lat/lon bounds may also cause a problem, if there were any contact details I'd complain to the owner.

Comment: Thank you for the hints! What puzzles me is that adding the wms layer with the Add WMS Layer tool in QGIS works but you can't make a local copy of it. Do you think that the QGIS tool just ignores the inconsistencies in the getcapabilities document?

Comment: there may be size limit on downloads? a test download at a resolution of 100 worked fine

Comment: I couldn't find any size limits but the reason why the QGIS Save as command didn't worked in the first place was that I selected the "Extend" option to save only a small detail of the terrestrial image. It turned out that the server doesn't support that.