# Polygonize tool error

Tags: qgis, polygonize

I'm using Qgis 3.0.1 and trying to polygonize a raster layer. I'm getting the following error:

> Processing algorithm…
>   AlgorithmDialog
>   Input parameters:
>   { 'INPUT' : 'crs=EPSG:4326&dpiMode=7&format=image/png&layers=klim-stat_temperatur:medeltemp_maj_yta&styles=&url=http://...', 'BAND' : 1, 'FIELD' : 'DN', 'EIGHT_CONNECTEDNESS' : False, 'OUTPUT' : 'C:/...' }
>
> GDAL command:
>   cmd.exe /C gdal_polygonize.bat crs=EPSG:4326&dpiMode=7&format=image/png&layers=klim-stat_temperatur:medeltemp_maj_yta&styles=&url=http://... "C:..." -b 1 -f "ESRI Shapefile" None DN
>   GDAL command output:
>
> gdal_polygonize [-8] [-nomask] [-mask filename] raster_file [-b band|mask]
>
> [-q] [-f ogr_format] out_file [layer] [fieldname]
>
> 'dpiMode' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>
> operable program or batch file.
>
> Invalid parameter - /png
>
> 'layers' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>
> operable program or batch file.
>
> 'styles' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>
> operable program or batch file.
>
> 'url' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>
> operable program or batch file.
>
> Execution completed in 0.86 seconds
>   Results:
>   {'OUTPUT': }
>
> Loading resulting layers
>   The following layers were not correctly generated.
>   C:/...
>   You can check the 'Log Messages Panel' in QGIS main window to find more information about the execution of the algorithm.

Any ideas of what it could be?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save the layer to a file, as shown in  https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/219658/187 and then polygonize.

Seems like WMS cannot be input layers for GDAL tools.