# DEFRA LiDAR Digital Surface Model WMS - unable to extract raster to hard disk

Tags: qgis, wms

I am in need of fine resolution elevation data from which I can extract slope and aspect for Oxfordshire county in England. I have found that the UK's Department for Environment Food & Rural Affairs data portal freely provides [1m resolution Digital Surface Model (DSF) for the UK, including already extracted slope and aspect products](https://environment.data.gov.uk/dataset/9ba4d5ac-d596-445a-9056-dae3ddec0178), hyperlinked.

I easily accessed the DSF as a WMS and was also able to view the slope and aspect products as ArcGIS Map Services, both is QGIS. Since these are only images, I want to the actual slope and aspect raster products to continue with my analyses. Hence, I am trying to convert these to rasters. I clicked on the links for the slope, aspect and DSM products in the above link, to get what format of data I can extract i.e. TIFF etc and I do not think there is any such info provided i.e. the metadata does not provide info on what is the raw data.

As per [this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/190927/save-a-wms-layer-on-your-hard-drive-via-qgis), I tried to export the slope and aspect data out as a GeoTIFF, which results in the error- [image]. I then tried converting to .vrt using the Raster> Miscellaneous>Build Virtual Raster and then work with .vrt, which firstly I could not open in QGIS let alone export out as a GeoTIFF.

How can I proceed to extract the slope and aspect data from this 1m resolution DSM product provided freely from the UK government?

Comment: The WMS doesn't give you the data just `A tinted shaded relief, which is an image showing what LIDAR looks like when loaded into specialist software`.  To get the data you'll need to use one of the Image Service endpoints

Comment: @nmtoken- the aspect and slope products on the page I have linked are Image Service endpoints

Comment: An Image service is an ESRI defined interface, it is not a WMS which is what the question as titled/tagged is asking about.   You man want to try using https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/ImageServerConnector/

Comment: At the bottom there is the option to Export Image https://environment.data.gov.uk/image/rest/services/SURVEY/LIDAR_Composite_1m_Last_Return_DSM_2022_Aspect/ImageServer

Comment: The EA/Defra DSM/DTM WMS endpoint URLs and the data download links are constantly down and/or changing from my experience. For example, the data download site throws an error: https://environment.data.gov.uk/survey and loading the WMS into QGIS tends to timesout. (as of Jan 24).